# New Array Values from Pointer not Passing

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a class assignment where I need to create a dynamic array, store two pointers in it, then swap them around.

I am almost complete, but for some reason I cannot pass the new stored values into the array.  I know the issue is the last two lines of code, which I know is wrong, but what I try to fix it with will not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void exchange(int*, int*, int* Arr[]);

int main()
{

    int* Arr = new int[5], i;  //Declare Dynamic Array
    cout << "Enter Number of Elements : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //setting all values in the Array to Zero.
        scanf_s("%d", Arr + i); 
    cout << endl;

    int a = Arr[3], b = Arr[4];

    cout << "The integers before swap : " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
    cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl << endl;

    exchange(&a, &b, &Arr);

    cout << "The integers after swap : \n" << endl;
    cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
    cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl;
    delete[] Arr;  //Delete Dynamic Array

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void exchange(int* a, int* b, int* Arr[]) {
    cout << "Please Enter two new intergers \n" << endl;
    cin >> *a;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> *b;
    cout << endl;
    Arr[3] = a; //These are the problem here, when I try *a it doesn't work
    Arr[4] = b;
}
```

Comment: Advice -- you really don't need all of this code to work out this issue.  Work on the [mcve], so that it would look [something like this](https://ideone.com/yVKzy3).

Comment: Thanks for your optimized code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables "a" and "b" are being updated inside the exchange() function, but you should update the array outside the function, that makes more sense and works correctly (you call the function, it changes the variables, then after return you update the array). Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void exchange(int*, int*, int* Arr[]);

int main()
{
    int* Arr = new int[5], i;  //Declare Dynamic Array

    cout << "Enter Number of Elements : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //setting all values in the Array to Zero.
    {
        printf("Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", Arr + i); 
    }

    cout << endl;

    int a = Arr[3], b = Arr[4];

    cout << "The integers before swap : " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
    cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl << endl;

    exchange(&a, &b);
    Arr[3] = a;
    Arr[4] = b;

    cout << "The integers after swap : \n" << endl;
    cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
    cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl;
    delete[] Arr;  //Delete Dynamic Array

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void exchange(int* a, int* b)
{
    cout << "Please Enter two new intergers \n" << endl;
    cin >> *a;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> *b;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void exchange(int*, int*, int* Arr[]);

int main()
{    
int* Arr = new int[5], i;  //Declare Dynamic Array
cout << "Enter Number of Elements : " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //setting all values in the Array to Zero.
    scanf("%d", Arr + i); 
    cout << endl;

int a = Arr[3], b = Arr[4];

cout << "The integers before swap : " << endl << endl;
cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl << endl;

exchange(&a, &b, &Arr);

cout << "The integers after swap : \n" << endl;
cout << "Fourth integer equals : " << Arr[3] << endl;
cout << "Fifth integer equals : " << Arr[4] << endl;
delete[] Arr;  //Delete Dynamic Array

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void exchange(int* a, int* b, int* Arr[]) {
cout << "Please Enter two new intergers \n" << endl;
cin >> *a;
cout << endl;
cin >> *b;
cout << endl;
Arr[0][3] = *a; //These are the problem here, when I try *a it doesn't work
Arr[0][4] = *b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `int* Arr[]` to `exchange` declares an array *of pointers* (really a pointer to a pointer; the "array" is just a convention).  Fix that, then remove the `&` from `&Arr` in the call.

To be clear, this may not make your program (whose requirements are unclear) *correct overall*; it's just the fix for the lines you indicated to make them have the effect you seem to have intended.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation.